# How do I install intel graphics drivers on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: graphics

On Ubuntu with Intel graphics the max resolution I can get is 1024x768 and setting a resolution manually causes errors after a restart. Is there I way I can fix it?

[image: ISPCI Output]

Comment: Welcome to AU. There is likely a fix, and I suspect no driver is needed. This question will benefit from some hardware specs, for example, the output of `lspci`.

Comment: I have added a picture of the ISPCI output

Comment: Isn't is a lot easier to copy.paste text, then to add a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Proprietary Drivers (if available) can be installed by clicking the gear in the upper right corner and selecting

System Settings... --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers

Make sure to do a little research about the driver you are installing (e.g. has it been heavily tested and verified to work).

Comment: There aren't any additional intel graphics drivers available.